# Rendering a dynamic robots.txt with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm replacing the default robots.txt file in rails with a dynamic one where I can control what the bots see on my site.

I've deleted the public/robots.txt file. In my PagesController, I've defined a robot's action

```
def robots
  respond_to :text
  render 'pages/robots.txt.erb'
  expires_in 6.hours, public: true
end
```

And in my routes

```
get '/robots.:format' => 'pages#robots'
```

I've created a **robots.txt.erb** file in the pages views directory to respond only when the site visited is the production site.

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
  User-Agent: *
  Allow: /
  Disallow: /admin
  Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap
<% else %>
  User-Agent: *
  Disallow: /
<% end %>
```

When I went to the site and robots.txt path, I got the error

Template is Missing

It wasn't finding the robots file in the pages view directory. I had previously named this file robots.html.erb and then renamed it to robots.txt.erb. The error persisted. Finally I just removed the respond_to line so now the robots action in PagesController is just

```
def robots
  render 'pages/robots.txt.erb'
  expires_in 6.hours, public: true
end
```

This works when I go to the URL.
I'm just curious whether or not this is good practice and if I'm losing anything by removing the respond_to action.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to start by creating a route like this

```
# config/routes.rb
#
# Dynamic robots.txt
get 'robots.:format' => 'robots#index'
```

Now we have to create a controller called robots

```
# app/controllers/robots_controller.rb
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
  # No layout
  layout false

  # Render a robots.txt file based on whether the request
  def index
    ...
  end

end
```

I hope that this help.